# Unfair die problem interpretation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> On throwing an unfair die, the probability of getting an odd number is $c$ and the probability of getting an even number is $2c$. Find $c$.

The correct solution to this problems is that the probability of getting 1,3,5 is each $c$ and probability of getting 2,4,6 is each $2c.$ Hence $3c+6c=1,$ which gives $c=1/9.$

My query is that why can't we interpret it as $p(\{1,3,5\})=c$ and $p(\{2,4,6\})=2c$  to get $c+2c=1$ and hence $c=1/3.$

Comment: You have a valid point. The specification is not clear. They should have said: For _each_ odd number, the probability is $c$, and for _each_ even number, the probability is $2c$.

Comment: Indeed, and *if they did not* say that, then the *incorrect* solution is $c=1/9$ while the *correct* solution to the problem *as quoted* is $c=1/3$.